# counting data and grouping by week in mysql

Tags: php, sql, counting, mysql5

this is my DB table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inspection_report` (
    `Inspection_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
    `Line` char(5) NOT NULL,
    `S` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `A` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `B` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `C` int(11) NOT NULL,
INSERT INTO `inspection_report` (`Inspection_datetime`,`Line`,`S`, `A`, `B`, `C`) VALUES
('2010-09-01 09:08:01','FA 05',0, 0, 0, 0),('2010-09-02 14:24:35','FA 07',0, 0, 1, 0),('2010-09-01 09:08:01','fa 05',0, 1, 1, 0),('2010-09-01 16:24:04','FA 03', 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

I have a lot of data for this table.how do i do if i want show the result like:

```
Line      1st week        2nd week      3rd week   4th week    5th week   total
   FA 03        20                32          10         12          35        109
   FA 05        12                 5          10         10          25         62
   FA 07         0                 0           1         1            0          2
```

there are a lot of data for a month. i want separate them counting for a week.if there is data that has reached about a week, then the script will automatically count them and share them in the 1st week,2nd week,3rd week,and so on. how do i do that? or are you have any idea? How about using `YEARweek()` command?

Comment: Months can be more than four weeks, and when do you consider the start/end of the week to be?

Comment: specify your mysql version and do you want to rely mysql or external script or task scheduler to achieve this?

Comment: have a look at [mysql event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html), only if you are using mysql 5+

Comment: @Sandy:  i'm using mysql 5.0 i'm newbie for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  A.Line,
  week1.1stweek,
  week2.2ndweek,
  ...
  IFNULL(week1.1stweek,0) + IFNULL(week2.2ndweek,0) + .... AS total
FROM
   inspection_report AS A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 1stweek FROM inspection_report WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 GROUP BY Line, WEEK, YEAR) AS week1 USING (Line)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 2ndweek FROM inspection_report WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 14 GROUP BY Line, WEEK, YEAR) AS week2 USING (Line)
...
GROUP BY Line
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this

```
SELECT
  n.name,
  w1.amount,
  w2.amount,
  ...
  IFNULL(w1.amount,0) + IFNULL(w2.amount,0) + .... AS total
FROM
   yourTable AS n
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT name, SUM(qty) AS amount FROM yourTable WHERE DAY(date) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 GROUP BY name
) AS w1 USING (name)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT name, SUM(qty) AS amount FROM yourTable WHERE DAY(date) BETWEEN 8 AND 14 GROUP BY name
) AS w2 USING (name)
...
```

Comment: is "BETWEEN 1 AND 7" means 7 days?

Comment: It means day of month is between 1 and 7 (inclusive)

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at the following :

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?bw=1280#78

the index page is here:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?bw=1280

example pivot query:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(empId,'Totals') AS EmpId,
  sums.2005, sums.2006, sums.2007,
  sums.2005 + sums.2006 + sums.2007 AS Sums
FROM (
  SELECT
    EmpID,
    SUM(IF(Yr=2005,sales,0)) As '2005',
    SUM(IF(Yr=2006,sales,0)) As '2006',
    SUM(IF(Yr=2007,sales,0)) As '2007'
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY EmpID WITH ROLLUP
) AS sums;
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| EmpId  | 2005     | 2006     | 2007     | Sums      |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 1      | 12000.00 | 18000.00 | 25000.00 |  55000.00 |
| 2      | 15000.00 |  6000.00 |     0.00 |  21000.00 |
| 3      |     0.00 | 20000.00 | 24000.00 |  44000.00 |
| Totals | 27000.00 | 44000.00 | 49000.00 | 120000.00 |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: its a good tutorial..but i can't resolve my problem if you not answer like my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can do using Pivot feature of SQL Server.  Refer following example.

```
CREATE TABLE MyData
(
    ItemDate DATETIME,
    ItemName VARCHAR(200),
    ItemQty  INT
)
GO

DECLARE @I INT 
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i < 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyData VALUES(GETDATE()-@I, 'NAME ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@I % 5), RAND()*100)
    SET @I = @I + 1
END
GO

SELECT ItemName, [1] AS 'WEEK-1', [2] AS 'WEEK-2', [3] AS 'WEEK-3', [4] AS 'WEEK-4'
FROM (SELECT ItemName, DATEPART(wk, ItemDate) WeekNum, ItemQty 
        FROM MyData) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(ItemQty)
    FOR WeekNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: i'm not understand at SQL-Server. this code not same with mysql.