# Learning LEFT JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

dear all.i newbie at web programming and until now i still have learn about MySQL syntax.
for now i start to use `LEFT JOIN` method. i know that this method use for make normalization between two or many tables. I have posted a question in SO, then I receive an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640729/counting-data-and-grouping-by-week-in-mysql) which make me confuse. I have modified that answer,but i still confuse because it use `LEFT JOIN` just for one table. whether the `LEFT JOIN` can be used in one table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` a table with itself, just like you can `JOIN` a table with itself.  Your purpose will usually be different, because the specific characteristic of a `LEFT JOIN` is ensuring a row in the output when no corresponding row exists on the right, of course; you can select those rows which have specifically been selected that way by checking for `NULL` for the "other part" of the row, the part that would normally come from the right-side table.

Consider for example a table `Product` with columns `ID`, primary key, `Name`, `Category`, and `Cost`; you want info about products that are cheapest in their category.  Then...:

```
SELECT P1.Name, P1.Category, P1.Cost
  FROM Product AS P1
  LEFT JOIN Product AS P2
  ON (P1.Category = P2.Category and P1.Cost > P2.Cost)
  WHERE P2.ID IS NULL
```

is an example of a "left join of a table to itself" which will answer the "you want" spec (if more than one item has the equal-lowest cost in a category you'll get them all -- the query actually gives you the items such that no item in their category is *cheaper* and has no checks for items of *equal* cost;-).